# Error include in Yiiibase.php - Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I have a project Yii. I call model from my controller to display data in a table

```
$model = new NewAccForm();
$post = Post::model()->find($model);
var_dump($post);
```

I run the code on an error:

> ```
>  PHP warning
>
> include(Post.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream:
> ```
>
> No such file or directory
>
> ```
> E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(427)
>
> 415                         {
> 416                             include($classFile);
> 417                             if(YII_DEBUG && basename(realpath($classFile))!==$className.'.php')
> 418                                 throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Class name "{class}" does not match class
> ```
>
> file "{file}".', array(
>       419                                     '{class}'=>$className,
>
> ```
> 420                                     '{file}'=>$classFile,
>
> 421                                 )));
>
> 422                             break;
>
> 423                         }
>
> 424                     }
>
> 425                 }
>
> 426                 else
>
> 427                     include($className.'.php');
>
> 428             }
>
> 429             else  // class name with namespace in PHP 5.3
>
> 430             {
> 431                 $namespace=str_replace('\\','.',ltrim($className,'\\'));
>
> 432                 if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($namespace))!==false)
>
> 433                     include($path.'.php');
>
> 434                 else
>
> 435                     return false;
>
> 436             }
> 437             return class_exists($className,false) ||
> ```
>
> interface_exists($className,false);
>
> ```
> 438         }
>
> 439         return true;
>
> Stack Trace
> #0    
> +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(427): YiiBase::autoload()
> #1    
>  unknown(0): YiiBase::autoload("Post")
> #2    
> –  E:\wamp\www\yii\amica\protected\controllers\front\ReportController.php(10):
> ```
>
> spl_autoload_call("Post")
>       05         '1'=>'Mới',
>       06         '2' => 'Đã Xóa'
>       07     );
>       08     public function actionIndex() {
>       09         $model = new ReportForm();
>       10         $post = Post::model()->find($model);
>       11         var_dump($post);
>       12         echo "
>
> ## Thông báo lỗi cho ban quản trị
>
> ";
>       13     }
>       14 
>       15     public function actionCreate() {
>       #3
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): ReportController->actionIndex()
>       #4
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("r" => "report"))
>       #5
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
>       #6
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array())
>       #7
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("")
>       #8
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("report")
>       #9
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
>       #10
>       –  E:\wamp\www\yii\amica\protected\components\WebApplicationEndBehavior.php(24):
>   CApplication->run()
>       19         // Attach the changeModulePaths event handler
>       20         // and raise it.
>       21         $this->onModuleCreate = array($this, 'changeModulePaths');
>       22         $this->onModuleCreate(new CEvent($this->owner));
>       23 
>       24         $this->owner->run(); // Run application.
>       25     }
>       26 
>       27     // This event should be raised when CWebApplication
>       28     // or CWebModule instances are being initialized.
>       29     public function onModuleCreate($event) {
>       #11
>        unknown(0): WebApplicationEndBehavior->runEnd("front")
>       #12
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(261): call_user_func_array(array(WebApplicationEndBehavior, "runEnd"),
>   array("front"))
>       #13
>       –  E:\wamp\www\yii\amica\index.php(13): CComponent->__call("runEnd", array("front"))
>       08 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
>       09 // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
>       10 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
>       11 
>       12 require_once($yii);
>       13 Yii::createWebApplication($config)->runEnd('front');
>       #14
>       +  E:\wamp\www\yii\amica\index.php(13): CWebApplication->runEnd("front")

why is there such a problem? and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Post::model()

Post model should be in path `protected/models/Post.php` or your model Post use namespace, than you should will set alias of `Yii::setPathOfAlias($alias,$path)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the model name in the file name and the class name inside models/Post.php because it's case sensitive, the first character must be capital letter.